# Javascript es5 filter function returns true

Tags: javascript

Hello i need a little help understanding the es5 filter function.

I'm trying to check if responseUID is true in membersUID.

From what i read checkUID should return false because responseUID is not in membersUID?

```js
var membersUID = [
{ playerUid: 162847201, displayName: "Player 1", isLeader: 1, canSell: 1 },
{ playerUid: 162847202, displayName: "Player 2", isLeader: 0, canSell: 0 },
{ playerUid: 162847203, displayName: "Player 3", isLeader: 0, canSell: 0 }
];

var responseUID = 162847204;
var checkUID = Object.keys(membersUID).filter(u => membersUID[u].playerUid == responseUID)

if (checkUID) {
  console.log('responseUID is in membersUID');
} else if (!checkUID) {
  console.log('responseUID is not membersUID');
}
```

So what am i doing wrong or what i read not true?

Comment: Even an empty array is also `truthy`, so check for the length of the result. Alternatively, you could just use the `find()` function. Also, you don't need `Object.keys()` here, just use `membersUID.filter()`.

Answer (score 1):

`membersUID` is an array so simply call it on that like so:

```
membersUID.filter(u => membersUID[u].playerUid == responseUID)
```

`filter` is called on an array and will return a new array when the condition is met/true`. i.e. in your case when`playerUid`===`responseUID` it will return an array of length 1

you can then access that object with `[0]`. but you could use `find` instead and that will return the object instead of an array

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) function, which returns true if at least one matches.
You also don't need to use `.keys` on an array to iterate over it.
filter returns an array, which is truthy.  You'd have to check length if you want to use it to check.

```js
var membersUID = [
{ playerUid: 162847201, displayName: "Player 1", isLeader: 1, canSell: 1 },
{ playerUid: 162847202, displayName: "Player 2", isLeader: 0, canSell: 0 },
{ playerUid: 162847203, displayName: "Player 3", isLeader: 0, canSell: 0 }
];

var responseUID = 162847204;
var checkUID = membersUID.some(({playerUid}) => playerUid === responseUID)

if (checkUID) {
  console.log('responseUID is in membersUID');
} else if (!checkUID) {
  console.log('responseUID is not membersUID');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The filter function returns an array and arrays are truthy values which means if you try to use them in if conditions they will always execute the if block.
as for what the filter function actually does, it runs through an array and returns another array with the elements that satisfy the condition you pass in the callback function.
so if you run the following:

```js
var membersUID = [
{ playerUid: 162847201, displayName: "Player 1", isLeader: 1, canSell: 1 },
{ playerUid: 162847202, displayName: "Player 2", isLeader: 0, canSell: 0 },
{ playerUid: 162847203, displayName: "Player 3", isLeader: 0, canSell: 0 }
];

var responseUID = 162847204;
var checkUID = membersUID.filter(u => u.playerUid === responseUID)
```

then `checkUID` will be an empty array `[]`.
you could use it in conditions like so

```js
if(checkUID.length){ // found something
   // run something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`filter` takes an array as input, and returns an array of the filtered items as the output.
Hence, it will be truthy for any valid input.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to do `Object.keys` to iterate over an `array`, I haven't tested it but I'm pretty sure that's the problem.

```
var membersUID = [
{ playerUid: 162847201, displayName: "Player 1", isLeader: 1, canSell: 1 },
{ playerUid: 162847202, displayName: "Player 2", isLeader: 0, canSell: 0 },
{ playerUid: 162847203, displayName: "Player 3", isLeader: 0, canSell: 0 }
];

var responseUID = 162847204;
var checkUID = membersUID.filter(u => u.playerUid === responseUID)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use find instead. Filter will return empty array which will be true in `if(checkUID)`

```js
var membersUID = [
{ playerUid: 162847201, displayName: "Player 1", isLeader: 1, canSell: 1 },
{ playerUid: 162847202, displayName: "Player 2", isLeader: 0, canSell: 0 },
{ playerUid: 162847203, displayName: "Player 3", isLeader: 0, canSell: 0 }
];

var responseUID = 162847204;
var checkUID = Object.keys(membersUID).find(u =>  

  membersUID[u].playerUid === responseUID

);


if (typeof checkUID !== 'undefined') {
  console.log('responseUID is in membersUID');
} else {
  console.log('responseUID is not membersUID');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this code will be usefull

```js
var membersUID = [{
    playerUid: 162847201,
    displayName: "Player 1",
    isLeader: 1,
    canSell: 1
  },
  {
    playerUid: 162847202,
    displayName: "Player 2",
    isLeader: 0,
    canSell: 0
  },
  {
    playerUid: 162847203,
    displayName: "Player 3",
    isLeader: 0,
    canSell: 0
  }
];

var responseUID = 162847204;
var checkUID = membersUID.filter(u => {
  return u.playerUid === responseUID;
})

console.log('checkUID: ', checkUID);
console.log('checkUID lenght: ', checkUID.length);
```